# Create x1,y1,x2,y2 columns of pgRouting a* algorithm from a GeoJSON/shapefile

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, astar

I have used pgRouting in PostgresSQL to routing using Dijkstra's algorithm. Now I need to do the same with a* algorithm, The A* algorithm needs x1,y1,x2,y2 values instead of geometry.

How can I convert line string geom to these values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [ST_StartPoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) / [ST_EndPoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html) with [ST_X](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) / [ST_Y](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html). Either you add new columns (`x1, x2, y1, y2`) to your edge table or you change the aStar query with the aforementioned functions.